# AngularJS ng-bind issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I am working on angular application. I need to bind two model variable using `ng-bind` and two variables from two different scope (One from parent and other from child scope). Is that possible?

Here is the code what I tried:

```
<input tabindex="2" id="{{ClientAC}}" ng-model="a.ClientAC" 
       ng-blur="clientFocusout()" ng-keydown="clientKeyDown($event)" />
```

Comment: use `ng-init` instead or show us your code.

Comment: Can u plz provide some code ?

Comment: <input tabindex="2" id="{{ClientAC}}" ng-model="a.ClientAC" ng-blur="clientFocusout()"  ng-keydown="clientKeyDown($event)" />

Comment: Edit it in your question.

Comment: Which variable is from which scope? Can't really tell from the code

Comment: I have two variables a.ClientAC and b.ClientAC

Comment: Provide some code please.